# How can I access my backed up files from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

How can I access my backed-up files from Ubuntu One?  The are of the file type .GPG  -- how can I open and access these files?

Comment: Where are those files? How did you back them up? Please edit your question to provide those details.

Answer (score 2):

You can access your files via https://one.ubuntu.com/files or sync them with your computer using the Ubuntu One client https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/

.GPG files are encrypted. You'll likely want to read this page for more guidance there https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto